Laravel Polymorphic Eloquent Relationship - Morph To Many - Oldest Of Many
I have a many-to-many polymorphic relationship defined like this:
public function images(): MorphToMany
{
    return $this->morphToMany(
        related: Image::class,
        name: 'imageable',
        table: 'imageables',
        foreignPivotKey: 'imageable_id',
        relatedPivotKey: 'image_id',
    );
}

I want to also define a one-to-many relationship like morphOne() that can do things like latestOfMany(), oldestOfMany(), and ofMany(). The problem I'm having is that morphOne() doesn't allow me to pass in the name of the pivot table (imageables in this example).
How do I create a relationship that accomplishes this?
